# How do I change application fonts in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, fonts

I'm trying to customize the look of Outlook, and am running into some problems getting fonts set how I like. If it matters, I'm using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7.

Here's what I've got so far:

- **Default email editor font** - `File/Options/Mail/Stationery and Fonts`
- **Navigation Pane font** - `View/Navigation Pane/Options/Font`
- **Folder email list** (like Inbox or a folder) - `View/View Settings/Other Settings`

  - This only applies to a single folder.
  - *How can I apply this globally?*
- **Outlook Today** - ???

  - *How to change the fonts, or anything, here?*

Also, why is this so convoluted? Shouldn't it all be under one Options or Settings panel? (I am hoping someone points me to a menu that I've missed.)

UPDATE: Is there really no way to comprehensively control the fonts and styles of Outlook? It's been around forever and this has not come up, even for accessibility concerns? The only things i can see not changing are email and documents from other people.

Comment: As far as I know, Outlook Today uses the standard Windows fonts decided on by your Desktop settings.